# Is it possible to completely remove "move between space" animations?

Tags: macos, spaces, animation

Is it possible to completely remove any "move between spaces" animation? I've tried toggling "Reduce Motion", but the animation is just replaced by a fade out. This makes it impossible to stream a full screen window on Discord, OBS and any other software, because the streamed window will shake (or fade) anytime you move spaces, when it should just remain fixed.

Example: https://youtu.be/4_e5AWsSIsM

Comment: I don't understand: if you want the Terminal to show continuously, why do you want to switch spaces? If you switch Spaces, shouldn't the Terminal window go away?

Comment: @benwiggy To do something else! For example, I'm coding on VIM, and my viewers are seeing the code. But eventually I need to answer some private messages in some social network. To do that, I move a space left, launch the browser, etc. I want my users to keep seeing VIM, not my private messages. And that's almost what happens, the only problem is that the VIM windows shakes out of nowhere, which is very annoying. So anytime I leave the terminal to do anything else on my mac, the screen will "shake" for all my viewers, just like I've shown on that video.

Comment: Do you have an iPad or another second screen? Or is your screen big enough to split it in half and only share a certain app window?

Comment: No replies at all. Sad limitations....